# 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, auth0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core v2.1 Razor Pages project in which I am working on implementing Auth0 for user authentication. After setting everything up, I attempted to build my project and am getting the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'
```

In order to set up Auth0, I had to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives nuget package. However, when trying to build my project, this is the error I get. If I remove the package, when I try and build the project, I get the following error:

```
Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives. Install/reference 
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 5.0.0 directly to your project to resolve this issue.
```

The following code is where the exception is being thrown:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I have read that InplaceStringBuilder does not exist in Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives anymore so I am assuming this is causing the problem. However, I don't see InplaceStringBuilder being used anywhere so I can't seem to figure out what it is even needed for.

Does anyone know a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you sure on asp.net core version and Primitives version?

Comment: The target framework is .NET Core 2.1 and Primitives 5.0.0 is installed.

Comment: Maybe you can try to update your package `Primitives` from 5.0.0 to 2.1.1.

Comment: @Yinqiu, I tried this and it is still throwing the same exception, which I don't understand, since it is still saying it couldn't load from assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives V 5.0.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably you have some package that uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` on `Version >= 5.0.0`

I had a similar problem a few days ago. In my scenario, I was working on an `ASP.NET Core v2.1 WEB API` and a dependency with a project that was using the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` on `Version="5.0.0"` caused the problem. I was able to solve the problem by downgrading that package from `Version 5.0.0` to `Version 2.1.0`.

Comment: Removing all the Microsoft.Extensions.* library references worked for me.

Comment: How to do the downgrading?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque by using the `NuGet Package Manager`. You can choose any available version of a package and update. If you use NuGet Manager (interface) in Visual Studio, you'll be able to see the package dependencies before installing or updating.

Comment: Just got the problem also for a WPF app referencing a .net standard lib (these one reference the abstraction nuget), version 3.1.0 is working also

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue. I was able to use the deps.json file in the solution (after building) to investigate which package was causing the issue - it was actually a nuget package that I had written myself. Same as you, downgrading the Abstractions package resolved the error.